# How do I rotate a rectangle of latitude and longitude? google maps,

Tags: javascript

I have a rectangle in google map, it needs to be rotated from the clicked point, the rectangle doesn't come out either. how to rotate a rectangle and the points inside it.

```
// 21 qator 22 qator va 71 qatorlarda

var inputHeight = document.querySelector("#inputHeight");
var inputWidth = document.querySelector("#inputWidth");
var inputX = document.querySelector('#inputx');
var inputY = document.querySelector('#inputy');
var inputa = document.querySelector('#alfa');
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyCcWRW3OffFhrY95FEcdTKCIQuuxKkEHNY';

function initMap() {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {
        lat: 39.760000,
        lng: 64.420000,
      },
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_TOP,
      zoom: 16,
      heading: 0,
      tilt: 0,
      mapId: "90f87356969d889c",
    });
    const buttons = [
      ["Rotate Left", "rotate", 5, google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER], // buni bosganda alfa 5 gradus qushiladi
      ["Rotate Right", "rotate", -5, google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER], // buni bosganda alfa -5 gradus buladi
    ];
    
    buttons.forEach(([text, mode, amount, position]) => {
      const controlDiv = document.createElement("div");
      const controlUI = document.createElement("button");
  
      controlUI.classList.add("ui-button");
      controlUI.innerText = `${text}`;
      controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
        adjustMap(mode, amount);
      });
      controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
      map.controls[position].push(controlDiv);      
    });
  
    const adjustMap = function (mode, amount) {
      switch (mode) {
        
        case "rotate":
          map.setHeading(map.getHeading() + amount);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };
    map.addListener('click', function (event) {
      var latitude = 39.760000; // Belgilangan nuqta latitude qiymati
      var longitude = 64.420000; // Belgilangan nuqta longitude qiymati
      
      // Draw a rectangle on the map
      
      
      var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#050505',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        map: map,
        // bounds: {
        //   north: latitude,
        //   south: latitude - (inputHeight.value - 1) * (inputX.value/111000),
        //   east: longitude + (inputWidth.value - 1) * (inputY.value/85380),
        //   west: longitude
        // },111000
      });
      // İki nokta arasındaki koordinatları tanımlayın
      // var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(39.760000, 64.420000);
      // var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(39.760011, 64.420011);

      // // İki nokta arasındaki mesafeyi hesaplayın
      // var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointB);

      // // 20 metreye ulaşmak için gereken oranı hesaplayın
      // var ratio = 20;

      // // Orantıyı kullanarak 20 metrelik noktaları bulun
      // var point20A = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(pointA, pointB, ratio);
      // var point20B = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(pointB, pointA, ratio);

      // // Çizgi oluşturun
      // var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      //   path: [point20A, point20B],
      //   geodesic: true,
      //   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      //   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      //   strokeWeight: 2
      // });
      
      var alfa = inputa.value // ana bu burchak ana shera tushishi kerak
      var cosin = Math.cos((Math.PI * alfa) / 180)
      var sinus = Math.sin((Math.PI * alfa) / 180)
      var heightx = inputX.value/111000
      var heighty = inputY.value/85380
      
      // Convert coordinates to elevation
      var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
      var locations = []
      for (var j = 0; j <= (inputHeight.value - 1);  j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= (inputWidth.value - 1); i++){
          locations.push({lat: latitude - (j * heightx * cosin) + ((i * heighty) * sinus) , lng: longitude + (i * (heighty * cosin)) + (j * heightx) * sinus});
        }
      }
       if let rotation = rotation, let center = zoneCenter {
        let radians = Double(rotation) * (Double.pi/180.0)
        print(radians)
        var newPoints: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        for point in squarePoints {
            let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude + (point.longitude - center.longitude) * sin(radians) + (point.latitude - center.latitude) * cos(radians)

            let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude + (point.longitude - center.longitude) * cos(radians) - (point.latitude - center.latitude) * sin(radians)

            newPoints.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude))
        }

        squarePointsWithRotation = newPoints
        squareOverlay = MKPolygon(coordinates: &newPoints, count: squarePoints.count)
        mapView.add(squareOverlay)
    }
}
      

      // var locations = [
      //   { lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
      //   { lat: latitude + (inputX.value/111000) * Math.sin((Math.PI * 45) /180), lng: longitude + (((inputY.value/85380) * Math.cos((Math.PI * 45) / 180))) },
        
      //   { lat: latitude - inputWidth.value * (inputY.value/85380) + (((inputY.value/85380) * Math.cos((Math.PI * 45) / 180))), lng: longitude + (((inputX.value/111000) * Math.cos((Math.PI * 45) / 180)))},
      //   { lat: latitude - inputWidth.value * (inputY.value/85380) + (inputX.value/85380) * Math.sin((Math.PI * 45) /180), lng: longitude + (inputX.value/111000)*inputHeight.value + (((inputY.value/85380) * Math.cos((Math.PI * 45) / 180)))},
        
        
      // ];
      var locationsList = document.getElementById('chiq')
      locations.forEach(function(location) {
        var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Yangi <li> elementini yaratamiz
        listItem.textContent = "Lat: " + location.lat + ", Lng: " + location.lng; // Matnni belgilaymiz
        locationsList.appendChild(listItem); // <ul> elementining ichiga <li> elementini qo'shamiz
      });
      var positionalRequest = {
        'locations': locations
      };
      var evalu = []
      elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
          if (results) {
            var gridParent = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
            gridParent.innerHTML = ""; // Jadvalni tozalash
            for ( var j =0; j < (inputHeight.value + 1); j++){
              var row = document.createElement("tr");
              for (var i = 0; i < (inputWidth.value ); i++) {
                var elevation = results[j* inputWidth.value + i].elevation.toFixed(2);
                evalu.push(results[j* inputWidth.value + i].elevation.toFixed(2));
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = elevation;
                row.appendChild(cell);
                gridParent.appendChild(row);
              }
            }
            
          }
        }
      });
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i],
            map: map,
            label: (i + 1).toString(),
            zIndex: locations[i].alt,   
          });
        }  
    });
  }

  // for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  //   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  //     position: locations[i],
  //     map: map
  //   });
  
  window.initMap = initMap;

// console.log(inputHeight.value * (inputX.value/1840))
// Evalu massivini HTML-da ko'rsatish
var evaluContainer = document.getElementById('evaluContainer');
evaluContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(evalu);
// console.log(locations)
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + apiKey + '&callback=initMap';
script.defer = true;
script.async = true;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

when you turn the card, the square must also turn. When I rotate the corner, it looks like a rhombus. When I turn it to 30 degrees, it misses 7 degrees, when I turn it to 60 degrees, it misses 9 degrees.

when the google map is rotated by 5 degrees, the rectangle should also rotate accordingly. only the points of the rectangle are output. I also posted the tested code.